# Derivative of $x \mapsto \left( 5 + x^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( x^3 + 1 \right)^{1/4}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x) = \left( 5 + x^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( x^3 + 1 \right)^{1/4}$$ What is $f'(x)$?

---

Can someone please help me to solve this? I am having a hard time how to start since fraction as exponent is new to me when it comes to derivatives. Please give me some advice.

Comment: what have you tried? show your steps.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

we have, $f(x)=(5+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} (x^3+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}$ , to get the derivative here, we use power rule and product rule, let's begin;

$f^{'}(x)=[\frac{1}{2}(5+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}-1}(5+x^2)^{'}] [(x^3+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}]+[(5+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} ][\frac{1}{4}(x^3+1)^{\frac{1}{4}-1}(x^3+1)^{'}]$

$f^{'}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(5+x^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}(2x)(x^3+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}+(5+x^2)^{{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{1}{4}(x^3+1)^{\frac{-3}{4}}(3x^2)$

$f^{'}(x)=\frac{1}{2(5+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}(2x)(x^3+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}+(5+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{4(x^3+1)^{\frac{3}{4}}}(3x^2)$

$f^{'}(x)=\frac{(x)(x^3+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}}{(5+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}+\frac{(3x^2)(5+x^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{4(x^3+1)^{\frac{3}{4}}}$

How was the above done?

Power rule says $x^n$ when differentiated, it becomes n$x^{n-1}$

product rule says h(x)k(x) when differentiated, it becomes $h
^{'}(x)k(x)+h(x)k^{'}(x)$